# Put on a TV show

Tags: word-usage, usage

If someone's watching a show and someone changes the channel, I know that it's natural to use "Change it back!" or "I was watching that!" but can this be used too:

> Put it on!

And when generally speaking:

> I put on X. (show)

Comment: In AmE we would not generally say *put on* NBC, although such a thing would be completely understood in context.  We would say **turn on** NBC.

Answer (score 1):

You are more likely to say **Put it back on** than just **Put it on**.

Generally speaking, you put on the television set. But people would understand **put on a show** to mean dialling it up on the television set.

The expression can also be used in the context of producing a show - in the sense of putting on a performance for an audience.

Comment: So what's the best way to express it when it is dialed up on the television?

Comment: If you were watching a channel that someone changed against your will, you could use either of your two suggestions or mine. It would be a good idea to add "please** or **Would you mind changing it back/putting it back on**

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish We don't say dialed up for television.

Comment: AmE almost never uses *put on*.  The common phrase is *turn on*.  *Turn on* the television and then *turn on* CBS.